# How to implement NSTimer in phone sdks?

Tags: iphone

I want to implement a timer functionality in my app. I know how to implement timer in iOS, but this is something difficult in my words, that I have a string that contains some values from the UITableview cell (like "red, blue, green, violet"). These are comma separated and I want to set a condition with the help of timer. My need is I want to share these values to GoogleDoc, single uploading is successful, but I can't do the multiple uploading, so my thought is to use the timer for uploading these values one by one in a fixed timing:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(myMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I want to set condition for, if red is default, so we don't want to set timer for that, after 2 seconds blue have to be uploaded, then after 2 seconds green, like all. So how to set a condition for this in "myMethod"?

This is my uploading code contains string "str" (`str` contains the move values):

```
- (IBAction)doUpload:(id)sender
{

   NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"NOTES:"]; 
    for (int i = 0; i<[appDelegate.notesArray count]; i++) { 
        UploadView *uploadview = (UploadView *)self.view; 
        if (uploadview != nil) 
        { 
            NSString * aString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:i]] ;
            [m_owner uploadString:aString]; 
        } 
        if (selected[i]) 
            [str appendFormat:@"%@ ,",[appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Please help me to do this. Thanks in advance.
EDIT:

```
- (IBAction)doUpload:(id)sender
{

   NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"NOTES:"]; 
    for (int i = 0; i<[appDelegate.notesArray count]; i++) { 
        UploadView *uploadview = (UploadView *)self.view; 
        if (uploadview != nil) 
        { 
            NSString * aString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:i]] ;
            //[m_owner uploadString:aString]; 
             [m_owner performSelector:@selector(uploadString:) withObject:aString afterDelay:i*20];
        } 
        if (selected[i]) 
            [str appendFormat:@"%@ ,",[appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:i]]; 
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Selected Values" message:str delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the NSObject's method:

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```

so in your code you can do this:

```
[m_owner performSelector:@selector(uploadString:) withObject:aString afterDelay:i*2];
```

which will schedule a 2i delay on each call (0,2,4,6,...).

The timer is set for you by this object. Of course all methods will be scheduled at the same time and then they will be run with this two seconds delay each. Of course it may happen that in cases of high network latency, the effective upload could happen with a different delay and still Google can reject it. In such case the best way to work is to do an upload and after that schedule the next one and so on...

Comment: thanks for your information,let me check it works or not.thanks vaerymuch.

Comment: so the cde looks like this?- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay{[m_owner performSelector:@selector(uploadString:) withObject:aString afterDelay:i*2];
}

Comment: it works greattttttttttttttttttttt,thank you verymuchhhhhhhhhhh.but some crash after 10 second i put i*10 ,but upload sucess

Comment: you should post the console log and the crash message.

Comment: there is no crash log available,i chekd.

Comment: are you sure you are not releasing the involved objects before the timer calls the methods?

Comment: sorry sir, i am not there in my office yteaterday.thats why i diidnt reply to your comment.my code looks like this .please see my edited question.thanks sir